# Bring next value after condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to fetch the next value after the condition is found. In this case, it is a row from 13/05/2021 the result I want to see is the row from 19/05/2021 Cte and CTE1 bring correct results.
I can't figure out what is wrong with my query.

[image]

```
<with cte as
(
select
customerid
,max(timestamp) as [Case Submitted]
,row_number() over (partition by [CustomerId] order by [CustomerId] ,max([timestamp]) desc) as rownum
   from Table1
      where substatus = 'Case Submitted'
         and timestamp > '2021-01-01'
Group by 
customerid
,timestamp
)
,CTE2 as
(
Select *
   from cte
     Where rownum = 1
),
CTE3 as
(
select
PS.customerid
,(PS.timestamp) as [Customer Support]
,row_number() over (partition by PS.customerid order by PS.customerid ) as rownum

  from Table1 PS
left join CTE2 C2 on C2.customerid = PS.customerid and C2.[Case Submitted] > PS.timestamp and C2.rownum =1

where status = 'Customer Support'
and timestamp > '2021-01-01'
Group by 
PS.customerid
,ps.timestamp
)
Select*
from CTE3>
```

Comment: in the first cte, if you group also by timestamp, then max timestamp can only be the grouped timestamp. Also, `(partition by col order by col)` is pointless.

Comment: If you provide queries to create the table and insert the sample data, then we will be able to check your query and maybe provide a better solution which we tested. Please provide DDL+DML

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Perhaps you could _explain_ what the "condition" is and how to identify the "next" value. Is the data type of all of the columns `pixel`?

Answer (score 0):

*untested notepad scribble*

```
with CTE1 as
(

    select
      customerid
    , [timestamp] as [Case Submitted]
    , rownum = row_number() over (partition by CustomerId order by [timestamp] desc)
    from Table1
    where substatus = 'Case Submitted'
      and [timestamp] > cast('2021-01-01' as date)
), 
CTE2 AS
(
    select
      PS.customerid
    , PS.timestamp as [Customer Support]
    , rownum = row_number() over (partition by PS.customerid order by PS.timestamp)
    from Table1 as PS
    join CTE1 as C1 
      on C1.customerid = PS.customerid 
     and C1.[Case Submitted] > PS.[timestamp] 
     and C1.rownum = 1
    where PS.status = 'Customer Support'
      and [timestamp] > cast('2021-01-01' as date)
)
select * 
from CTE2
where rownum = 1
```